# TypeError: no numeric data to plot after creating a dataframe from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to plot a dataset contained in a dictionary:

```
my_dict = [{'A': [0.7315847607219574],
  'B': [0.5681159420289855],
  'C': [0.9999999999999997],
  'D': [0.5793801642856945],
  'E': [0.6867350732769776],
  'F': [0.7336804366512104]},
 {'A': [0.4758837897858464],
  'B': [0.4219886317147244],
  'C': [0.6206223617183635],
  'D': [0.3911170612926995],
  'E': [0.5159829508133175],
  'F': [0.479838956092881]},
 {'A': [0.7315847607219574],
  'B': [0.5681159420289855],
  'C': [0.9999999999999997],
  'D': [0.5793801642856945],
  'E': [0.6867350732769776],
  'F': [0.7336804366512104]}]
```

then

```
df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
df.plot(kind="barh")
plt.show()
```

`dtypes` is showing object type for all, and the syntax error `TypeError: no numeric data to plot`

I've exhausted most of my brain cells trying to figure this out but with no avail. All help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extracting the number from the list does the job

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


my_dict = [{'A': [0.7315847607219574],
            'B': [0.5681159420289855],
            'C': [0.9999999999999997],
            'D': [0.5793801642856945],
            'E': [0.6867350732769776],
            'F': [0.7336804366512104]},
           {'A': [0.4758837897858464],
            'B': [0.4219886317147244],
            'C': [0.6206223617183635],
            'D': [0.3911170612926995],
            'E': [0.5159829508133175],
            'F': [0.479838956092881]},
           {'A': [0.7315847607219574],
            'B': [0.5681159420289855],
            'C': [0.9999999999999997],
            'D': [0.5793801642856945],
            'E': [0.6867350732769776],
            'F': [0.7336804366512104]}]

for entry in my_dict:
    for k,v in entry.items():
        entry[k] = v[0]
df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
df.plot(kind="barh")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for the help. Are you aware why it's not capturing the numbers and denoting the whole dataframe as object type?

Comment: @AliJ Not sure I have an answer to your question. I hope the workaround is good enough for you.

Comment: It did, thank you a lot.